Generating a plot of the Hartree potential in a certain direction
Good morning everyone, it's my first question here, so please forgive me all the possible errors.
For training purposes, I've done a Siesta+Transiesta calculation (using Siesta 4.1-b4 version) for a simple 1D linear Gold chain, made of 25 atoms: 10 atoms the electrodes and 5 atoms the device region.
I wanted to visualize a V(z) vs z plot in order to see what happens when the bias is applied and the difference between the Hartree potential obtained in a standard PBC calculation.
In order to do that, I inserted the flag
SaveElectrostaticPotential .true.

obtaining, after the calculation, a .VH file.
My question is: how can I "slice" this file up, obtaining the wanted plot?
Let me know if I left something out!
Thank you!

+1. Welcome to our community.

There is the SISL package developed by prof. @nickpapior (one of the developers of SIESTA).

Thank you @Camps , I used it and it worked! For anyone wondering i used the command lne script sgrid with the options --average x --average y, to obtain the plot over z. All that's needed is the ElectrostaticPotential.grid.nc file and that's all. Thank you again!

Good to know! Could you add an elaborated answer?

And, please don't use beta releases when there are official releases! :)

This can indeed be done with the sisl package.
There are multiple ways to use the utilies shipped with sisl.
And do note, the utility can parse any files that implements a read_grid method in sisl, so VASP files would also work. :)
sgrid ElectrostaticPotential.grid.nc --average x --average y --out z.dat

To calculate the difference between two grids do
sgrid ElectrostaticPotential.grid.nc --diff ../base/ElectrostaticPotential.grid.nc --average x --average y --out diff_z.dat

That would be the simplest solution if one does not go about doing this in Python scripts:
import sisl as si

base = si.Grid.read("../base/ElectrostaticPotential.grid.nc")
new = si.Grid.read("ElectrostaticPotential.grid.nc")
diff = new - base
z = diff.average(0).average(1).grid.ravel()
# now you have the z values for each grid-point along the z direction
print(z)

